# SQL for change of model structure

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have already a model like this:

```
class MyBase(models.Model):
    field_a = models.IngetField()
    field_b = models.IngetField()

class Class1(MyBase):
    field_c = models.IngetField()

class Class2(MyBase):
    field_c = models.IngetField()
```

That means and autoincrement mybase_ptr_id and a field_c field on each Class1 and Class2.

Because of design reasons we want to change the schema to:

```
class Class1(models.Model):
    field_a = models.IngetField()
    field_b = models.IngetField()
    field_c = models.IngetField()

class Class2(models.Model):
    field_a = models.IngetField()
    field_b = models.IngetField()
    field_c = models.IngetField()
```

This one instead, would require an autoincrement id and fields field_a, field_b, field_c(the most common aproach I guess).

Is there an established or reccomended way to modify the structure of the tables? I am using postgresql.

I suppose the basic way for each table:

1. Create a new id column.
2. Fill the same info I already have on mybase_ptr_id.
3. Convert id to a serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY.
4. Reindex id next value.
5. Add field_a and field_b columns.
6. Match corresponding for field_a, field_b values from MyBase table.
7. Drop column from mybase_ptr_id.

Am I missing any kind of important issues about this? I would like to read your reccomendations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would recommend using South for changing your database models, it can handle quite a few things automatically for you.

But changing something as drastic as this while retaining data will require a bit of manual work.

I think you have the outline mostly there, although I don't think you need to convert to serial later. I think you can create the `id` column a serial from the beginning. Just add the primary key index after you've copied the data.

So... my advice:

1. Add serial `id`, field_a and field_b with field_a and field_b as null fields.
2. `update table set id = mybase_ptr_id, field_a = other_table.field_a, ...`
3. update your sequence to start at `select max(id) from table`
4. make `id` a primary key and the other fields not null
5. drop mybase_ptr_id

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed steps. I was having problems with the 4th. couldn't make id a PK because mybase_ptr_id was already a PK... so better renamed id column added a new secuence starting from the max id  from MyBase table and droped the constraint that tied to mybase